# Dynamically increase text area height using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a text area and the size is growing as I type in the data(using KeyUp function), the problem is, when I save the text area, height is going back to its orignial height(ex: before I save, the height of the text area is 94 px and after I save it, the height of the text area is going back to its original height(45 px).

So I was trying to get the height of the text area before the ajax call and trying to apply the height after the ajax call. Below is the code:

```
<div id="FidningErrorDiv">
    <textarea class="form-control" maxlength="2000" placeholder="Finding" id="Findings" onchange="RemoveErrorBorder(this)">@Model.Finding.Finding</textarea>
</div>
```

```js
var divheight = $("#FidningErrorDiv").height;
$('#dvFindingBody').html(response); // Existing code
$("#Fidnings").css({
    height : divheight 
})
```

It's not working when I tried this way. Please suggest me to apply the height.

Comment: Can you show us the full JavaScript / jQuery, also the full HTML will help too.

Comment: Does saving means that you are clearing off the data from the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height` is not the correct syntax. You are using it like a property , but it is a [method](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and you should access it like `height()`.

Also, you had some typos in your code. jQuery selector`(#Findings`) was spelled wrong !

This should work.

```
var divheight = $("#FidningErrorDiv").height();

//divheight=divheight+150;  

$('#dvFindingBody').html("replace response variable here"); 
$("#Findings").css({  height : divheight });
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/yepakod/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Or you may use the `height()` method to set the new value

```
$("#Findings").height(300);
```